# Most recent way to secure a website/database

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the best most recent way to secure access to a website with a database. The website is built in PHP and Mysql. Currently, I'm thinking of using md5 and salt or blowfish and salt.

I don't have a ssl server yet so I am not looking at that. I just need to make sure the data is safe.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question - I have no idea what your website is built to do, what functions you provide to users, or even what you're trying to prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be entirely helpful, but if you're trying to secure access *generically*, it's probably best to use Apache [mod_auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html) or something similar at the server level rather than trying to write your own authentication system.

Even if you do choose to use a php/mysql authentication system, I'd still advise you not to write your own, but to use a framework ([symfony](http://symfony.com/), etc.) or package that has these capabilities built in.

Securing authentication to a website properly is a very large subject with many pitfalls and I'd say it's far better to work with an accepted standard vs. rolling your own.